# Bot Framework Composer - Installed packages do not appear in 'Installed' menu

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am creating a bot using Bot Framework Composer following the instructions in the tutorial.

Tutorial URL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial-create-weather-bot#add-interruptions-to-the-conversation-flow

The tutorial states that the Project Readme appears when the 'Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel' package is installed. But it doesn't appear.

The tutorial also states that 'CancelDialog' and 'HelpDialog' are displayed on the authoring canvas. But I don't see it.

Also, the installed packages do not appear in the 'Installed' menu in Package Manager.

I don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which composer version are you using ?

Comment: I am using the v2.1.1.

Comment: If possible can share the code path ( ex: github )

Comment: code path : https://github.com/joony92/weather_bot

Comment: its working for me have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: I set it to Allow access for private and public networks.
For reference, the OS version of my computer is Windows 10 Pro 2004 and the Region is Korea.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can install whatever I want and it seems to be successful (when I open the solution in visual studio, I can see the nuget package) but the composer isn't picking it up. The list of installed packages stays empty and I cannot use the functionality in the composer.

Comment: @joony Can you create a new project from the "Enterprise People Bot" template from within the composer? I am getting an error here, too, when I navigate to "Package Manager" after the creation has finished. You, too? Perhaps this is related?

Comment: @joony In the generated folder structure in the folder "schemas" - do you have a sdk.schema file there?

Comment: I found the cause of the problem.
It was because the user name of the Windows local user account was Korean (in my case) not English.
After changing the user name to English, I tried again and it worked normally.

Comment: @timtos : (After changing the user name to English) I can add a new bot from the 'Enterprise People Bot' template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

It was because the user name of the Windows local user account was Korean (in my case) not English.

After changing the user name to English, I tried again and it worked normally.

Unfortunately, I don't have a deep understanding of this issue, so it's difficult to explain in detail.

I look forward to a detailed explanation from someone who has a deep understanding of this issue.

Comment: I created a ticket for this issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8781